# 403 forbidden on nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm trying to create a localhost server with nginx.  I'm getting a **403 Forbidden** on my page. Here's my nginx error log:

```
2013/03/30 20:39:18 [error] 12161#0: *1 directory index of "/home/mike/Projects/606club/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /606club/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #for .html sites
    location / {
        root   /home/mike/Projects;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #for .php sites
    location ~ \.php$ {
            root /home/mike/Projects;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /opt/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

My site at the URLs below gives me the following:

**works**

```
http://<myhost>/home/mike/Projects/thoth/index.html
```

**403 Forbidden error**

```
http://<myhost>/home/mike/Projects/606club/index.php
```

My folders have permissions 755.

Comment: That URL didn't give you a 403 Forbidden error, according to your error message; a different URL did.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `index.php` to your `index` directive, if you want requests for `/` to be served by `/index.php`.

Comment: I added index.php and now I'm getting and an nginx error "An error occured.".  In my error log same error.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Inside /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf I had to change

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

to

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo chmod 755 index.php
```

in my case this works, before this I cant see index.php but can index.html